# Replace only top-level parent table elements with divs, not child tables

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, parent, replacewith

I am looking to replace a table and it's rows and cells with divs, but the script I have found replaces every child table and their descendents with divs too, which I do not want.  Child tables should remain tables.

How do I just target the top-level parent table and not any of the children tables?

```
    $('table.calendar-header').each(function (){
        $(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
            .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
            .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='tr'")
            .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
            .replace(/<td/gi, "<div class='td")
            .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</div>")
            .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
        );
    });
```

I've tried inserting :first-child and .first() into the script in various places to no avail.

Here's what the HTML looks like before script runs [note that I left out content from child tables in this code snippet].  You can see that there are tables within the parent table. I want those to remain as is, not be replaced.

```
<table class="calendar-header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="0" style="">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table class="calendar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"></table>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="eventNav"></div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">
                <table class="calendar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: I've read over the jquery page on replaceWith(), but I don't see any suggestings on targeting parent items only or excluding children. Thanks.

Comment: You are doing a string replace? Cos when you call `html()` it returns all the string within that tag, and you are just replacing all the tbodys with a new string.

Comment: can you share the html sample also

Comment: ok, I added an HTML sample.  I didn't include details about the children tables, to simplify it a good bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it like shown below.

In order for this to work, your child tables cannot have a class `calendar-header`. If they do, you'll have to change the check `if ($(obj).closest("table").hasClass("calendar-header"))` to something unique to your parent table.

As a side note, just be aware that if your user is using Firefox and AdBlockPlus, any div with class `thead` will be mistaken by `theAd` ("the advertisement"), and your div will be hidden by the plugin (it will dynamically add a link to `elemhide.css`). So I changed the resulting classes names to `divTable`, `divThead`, etc:

```
$('table.calendar-header').each(function (){
    // It's important to go from farthest tag to the nearest.
    $(this).find("th").each(replacer);
    $(this).find("td").each(replacer);
    $(this).find("tr").each(replacer);
    $(this).find("tbody").each(replacer);
    $(this).find("thead").each(replacer);
    replacer(0, this); // replace the table tag
});

function replacer(idx, obj) {
    tagName = capitalizeFirstLetter($(obj).prop("tagName").toLowerCase());
    if ($(obj).closest("table").hasClass("calendar-header")) {
        $(obj).replaceWith("<div class='div" + tagName + "'>" + obj.innerHTML + '</div>');
    }
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!!  I was about to give up and just hide the first and third TDs for mobile, but they have content I really wanted to include.

Answer (score 0):

Every table has a td, right?

```
var cur = $('td').closest('table');
while (cur.closest('table').length > 1)
{
    cur = cur.closest('table');
}
```

Comment: The finalized version of cur will have all top tables.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how this is to work with my current script.  I thought maybe I'd start with your script and then use "cur" in place of "this" in mine, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to manually extract out each tag, and rebuilt the DOM in JQuery. Using the replace method will just blindly replace all the requested strings.